# react native save screen to image issue (react-native-view-shot module)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get [React-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) to work, but have been stymied by what I believe to be some sort of incompatibility in terms of the module and the version of React Native tools which I have installed. The core issue seems to be with this snippet of code:

```
import { ReactNative, NativeModules, Modules, findNodeHandle } from "react-native";
/*
const {} = NativeModules;
*/
const {
  RNViewShot,
} = ReactNative;

export function takeSnapshot(
  view: number | ReactElement<any>,
  options ?: {
    width ?: number;
    height ?: number;
    filename ?: string;
    format ?: "png" | "jpg" | "jpeg" | "webm";
    quality ?: number;
    result ?: "file" | "base64" | "data-uri";
  }
): Promise<string> {
  if (typeof view !== "number") {
    const node = findNodeHandle(view);
    if (!node) return Promise.reject(new Error("findNodeHandle failed to resolve view="+String(view)));
    view = node;
  }
  return RNViewShot.takeSnapshot(view, options);
}

export default { takeSnapshot };
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating `RNViewShot.takeSnapshot`)

Comment: did you able to solve this problem? I had a same kind of problem but I was able to solved it. I don't know that solution is match with your one. but anyway tell me if need any help.