# How can I take a screenshot (View) with a TouchableHighlight?

Tags: react-native

The Error has been resolved as per your guidelines.

But still can not take and save the screeshot of the desired ViewShot, where it has a react image.

I need to take and save the screeshot in the memory of my device.

Can you tell me if I'm on the right track or would I have another way to do it? Thanks!

Follow my current code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";
import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";

const zooMais = require('../imgs/zooMais.png');
const zooMenos = require('../imgs/zooMenos.png');
const imgScreeshot = require('../imgs/screeshot.png');

const btnZooMais = ()=>{
    alert("Zoo Mais");
  }
const btnZooMenos = ()=>{
    alert("Zoo Menos");
  }
const capitureScreen = ()=>{
        captureScreen({
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.9,
        }).then(
            uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
            error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
            );
}

        
export default class Monitor extends Component {
    
    componentDidMount () {
        this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
          console.log("do something with ", uri);
        });
      }
  
    render() {
        return (
           
            <View>
         <ViewShot ref="viewShot" options={{ format: "jpg", quality: 0.9 }} >                 
   <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}} style={ style.video } />                  
        </ViewShot>
                
                <View style={style.menu}>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={  btnZooMais } >
                            <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={zooMais } />
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>  

                    <View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={ capitureScreen }>
                      <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={ imgScreeshot } />
                    </TouchableHighlight >
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ btnZooMenos } >
                         <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={ zooMenos } />
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    corpo: {
    },
    menu:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    imgMenu:{
        //margin: 15
      },
      video: {
          width: 400, 
          height: 450
        }
});
```

Comment: Shoudn't it be `import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";`

Comment: Are you sure you have 'react-native-view-shot' installed properly for the device you are attempting to run the code on?

Comment: Eu instalei a versão original de reação = "0.44.0"

Comment: I installed react-native version = "0.44.0",  I installed react-native-view-shot@2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not have either linked the package or rebuilt the app after linking.

Try

```
 $ react-native link react-native-view-shot
 $ react-native run-{ios|android}
```

Comment: when I run the react-native link react-native-view-shot command in the CMD project directory. The react-native run-androi command does not run completely.
Returns the error below in cmd. It seems to be react-native and react-native-view-shot version error. I'm new to react-native, any help is welcome.

Comment: error returned                                                                                                                                                   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\dagso\Desktop\Projetos RN\AppCameraV1\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v7'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

Comment: it seems that this topic the guy managed to solve this problem of unpacking but did not describe the solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/40907872/8217276

Comment: solve the problem by running a clear project and rebuild